# Objects are not valid as a React child - Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm creating a Storybook for my Design System and I came across the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {icon, label, content}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
  at mapIntoArray (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-LWCIAKPC.js?v=909d2fcb:701:31))
  at mapChildren (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-LWCIAKPC.js?v=909d2fcb:736:11))
  at Object.toArray (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-LWCIAKPC.js?v=909d2fcb:754:18))
  at parseReactElement2 (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/@storybook_react_preview.js?v=909d2fcb:512:49))
  at reactElementToJsxString2 (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/@storybook_react_preview.js?v=909d2fcb:848:21))
  at /node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/@storybook_react_preview.js?v=909d2fcb:1437:173
  at /node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-LWCIAKPC.js?v=909d2fcb:737:25
  at mapIntoArray (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-LWCIAKPC.js?v=909d2fcb:660:31))
  at Object.mapChildren [as map] (/node_modules/.cache/.vite-storybook/deps/chunk-LWCIAKPC.js?v=909d2fcb:736:11))
```

**Tabs.stories.tsx**

```
import { Tabs } from './index';
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react"
import { Gear, PaintBrush, PencilSimple } from "phosphor-react";

const items = [
    {
        icon: <PencilSimple size={20} />,
        label: 'Item 1',
        children: <div>Item 1 content</div>
    },
    {
        icon: <Gear size={20} />,
        label: 'Item 2',
        children: <div>Item 2 content</div>
    },
    {
        icon: <PaintBrush size={20} />,
        label: 'Item 3',
        children: <div>Item 3 content</div>
    },

];

export default {
    title: 'Components/Tabs',
    component: Tabs,
    args: {
        children: items,
        type: "default"
    },
} as Meta

export const Default:StoryObj = {

}
```

**TabsProps.types.ts**

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Tab {
    label?: string;
    icon?: ReactNode,
    content: ReactNode
}

export interface TabsProps {
    type?: "default" | "secondary";
    defaultValue?: string;
    children: Tab[];
}
```

If you import the component in another file, it works perfectly with the same data, for example:

```
<Tabs defaultValue={'tab-0'} children={items} />
```

but inside the Storybook it does not work, showing the error mentioned above.

I've put the example in this link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-monad-ql4h2e?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. For some unknown reason, I cannot use the word "**children**" in the interface

When I changed from **children** to **items** the problem was solved

**Before:**

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Tab {
    label?: string;
    icon?: ReactNode,
    content: ReactNode
}

export interface TabsProps {
    type?: "default" | "secondary";
    defaultValue?: string;
    children: Tab[];
}
```

**After**

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface Tab {
    label?: string;
    icon?: ReactNode,
    content: ReactNode
}

export interface TabsProps {
    type?: "default" | "secondary";
    defaultValue?: string;
    items: Tab[];
}
```